# Image/Texture scroll/shift (wrap)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Does anyone know whether libGDX has a method for scrolling/shifting an image/texture *within itself*?

To explain; I would like to be able to scroll the contents (pixels) of an image, either vertically or horizontally within its own *region*. For example, if an image is shifted 1 pixel to the right, all pixels move 1 to the right and those on the right-most-edge are wrapped to the left-most-edge. The image size does not change, only the positioning of the pixels within it change.

I have mainly been working with the Sprite class, it can do a lot (scale, rotate, etc) but shift/scroll as I need it, isn't there.

Before writting the method myself, I thought I'd ask here...

The following worked for me, this was provided by Kush:

```
float delta = 0f;

// In the Actors act method
delta += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

// Horizontal
batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, width, height, 0 + delta * 10, 1, 1 + delta * 10, 0);

// Vertical
batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, width, height, 1, 0 + delta * 10, 0, 1 + delta * 10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need Sprite for this, draw directly Texture using batch. For wrapping first set

```
Texture texture = new Texture("example.png");
texture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
```

then draw using uv

```
batch.draw(texture, x, y, width, height, u, v, u2, v2);
```

or any other method that suits you in SpriteBatch.

Comment: I have finally been able to test what you've written. I gave you a +1 as the batch.draw(texture, ...) has a lot of options, but no tick (as yet) because I haven't been able to get the scrolling to work.

Comment: `batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, width, height, 0 + delta*10, 1, 1 + delta*10, 0);`

delta could be Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime().

Comment: Thanks, that works - I thought I had already tested something like that ... guess not.